# PROGRESS ODBC GROUP BY CLAUSE

Tags: sql, odbc, progress

Im still improving my query writing skills and i have little problem with select which uses stastical function like average max etc. Firstly i wrote simple query based on single table and it works perfect:

```
select e.Article, avg(e.Price) as 'Average', max(e.Price) as 'Max', min(e.Price) as 'Min' from pub.E_ArtPrice e
group by e.Article
order by e.Article
```

Next step was to create something little more complicated to get information which is really useful for me:

```
Select m.Part, m.Quantity, m.OnHand, m.postingdate, m.storagearea, p.MEM_PostingCode_ID, koss.Description, ko.Carrier, avg(e.price) as 'Average', max(e.price) as 'Max', min(e.price) as 'Min'
from pub.MLL_Movements m inner join pub.MEM_PostingCode p on (m.MEM_PostingCode_Obj = p.MEM_PostingCode_Obj)
left outer join pub.s_Carrier ko on (m.CostAccObject_Obj = ko.S_Carrier_Obj)
left outer join pub.s_CostCentre kos on (m.CostAccObject_Obj = kos.S_CostCentre_Obj)
left outer join pub.S_CostCentreSpr koss on (kos.CostCentre = koss.CostCentre)
left outer join pub.E_ArtPrice e on (m.Part = e.Article)
where p.MEM_PostingCode_ID = 'AUKJ'
```

I didn't put the group by clause here because after many tries it didnt work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWide.jpg)

Comment: "Didn't" work is too vague.  You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of why your query doesn't work.

Comment: Is this an OpenEdge database?

Answer (score 0):

All your `select` columns other than the `aggregate columns` should be in your `group by` clause hence try the below

```
   Select m.Part, m.Quantity, m.OnHand, m.postingdate, m.storagearea, p.MEM_PostingCode_ID, koss.Description, ko.Carrier, avg(e.price) as 'Average', max(e.price) as 'Max', min(e.price) as 'Min'
    from pub.MLL_Movements m inner join pub.MEM_PostingCode p on (m.MEM_PostingCode_Obj = p.MEM_PostingCode_Obj)
    left outer join pub.s_Carrier ko on (m.CostAccObject_Obj = ko.S_Carrier_Obj)
    left outer join pub.s_CostCentre kos on (m.CostAccObject_Obj = kos.S_CostCentre_Obj)
    left outer join pub.S_CostCentreSpr koss on (kos.CostCentre = koss.CostCentre)
    left outer join pub.E_ArtPrice e on (m.Part = e.Article)
    where p.MEM_PostingCode_ID = 'AUKJ'
group by m.Part, m.Quantity, m.OnHand, m.postingdate, m.storagearea, p.MEM_PostingCode_ID, koss.Description, ko.Carrier
```